# Time elapsed since app was active is wrong value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a SwiftUI/SpriteKit project.

I'm trying to get the **time elapsed** between a) now, and b) when my app was last active. This should be extremely simple, but there's a problem.

I have a timer (used for an in-app clock) that calls a function once per second. In this function, I store the result of `CACurrentMediaTime()` in a variable called `oldTime`. This means that `oldTime` will be *current* as long as the app is in the foreground.

So, the strategy is the following:

1. Record the current time while the app is active via `CACurrentMediaTime()`. This is `oldTime`.
2. Upon putting the app into the background, call `.invalidate()` on the timer, thus ensuring that the timer callback doesn't run while the app is backgrounded.
3. Compare `oldTime` to `CACurrentMediaTime()` when the app returns from the background. `CACurrentMediaTime() - oldTime` should give the time elapsed.

This strategy works perfectly when testing on a device through Xcode. However, when testing via TestFlight, the time elapsed is *way* off. If I put the app into the background, then return 10 minutes later, the time elapsed might be something like 1 minute. So, it *does* register some time elapsing, which is curious.

In `SceneDelegate`, I have the following code that invalidates and restarts the timer depending on state:

```
func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
     //The app is being interrupted. Invalidate the timer so it doesn't run in the background and screw up the time elapsed.
     MainData.appWideTimer?.invalidate()
     MainData.appWideTimer = nil
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
     //The app is active again. Start the timer.
     mainData.startTheTimer() //Sets a timer via Timer.scheduledTimer()
}
```

Elsewhere, I have the timer's callback, in which the time elapsed is calculated:

```
@objc func updateClock() {
     let now = CACurrentMediaTime()
     let timeSinceAppWasActive: Double = now - oldTime

     //timeSinceAppWasActive will be incorrect when tested via TestFlight

     oldTime = now
}
```

I'm all out of ideas, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: where is oldTime stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `CACurrentMediaTime`. I believe that is based on the time since the device was last started, ignoring time when it is asleep. (The docs say it is based on `mach_absolute_time`, and the docs on `mach_absolute_time` say that the value "start[s] at an arbitrary point", and that "this clock does not increment while the system is asleep.")

CAMediaTime is for use in Core Animation and timing animation sequences. It gives values that increase starting "at an arbitrary point" and run continuously during an animation, but there's no guarantee that it will run continuously while your app is in the background.

You should be using the result of calling `Date()`. That gives you a time that should always be correct (assuming the device's clock is accurate.)

The difference between 2 Date values is the number of seconds (including fractions of a second, to with sub-millisecond accuracy) that have elapsed between the calls to the `Date()` function, and should be correct despite device sleep or restarts.

Comment: Wow, I was totally misunderstanding the purpose of `CACurrentMediaTime()`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a timer for this sort of thing, because timers don't run in the background. Nor do you need to. And the use of CACurrentMediaTime is completely wide of the mark.

To know when the app became inactive, just look at the clock and write down the time (namely `Date()`) when the app becomes inactive. When you want to know how long it has been since then, just look at the clock again and subtract.

Comment: 1) I don't need or want to run a timer in the background; that's not why I'm using a timer. 2) What's wrong with `CACurrentMediaTime()`? Why would that produce an incorrect value? 3) The timer isn't really the issue, insofar as it's just a convenient way to record the current time, as the timer is already required for another functionality (an in-app clock). 4) I will try using `Date()` instead, and I will try simply recording the value upon entering the background instead of constantly updating it in `updateClock`.